# I accidentally used BTC xpub key to generate HD wallet addresses for BCH, can I recover funds?

Tags: electrum, bitcoin-cash, bip32-hd-wallets, exodus

I am using Exodus wallet and an eCommerce plugin to accept cryptocurrency payments. To generate the HD wallet addresses I needed to provide an xpub key. I accidentally used the BTC xpub key instead of the BCH xpub key. They are different. Is it possible to recover my funds somehow or are they lost forever?

Answer (score 1):

The answer, surprisingly, is yes. You need to change the derivation path of your BCH wallet to that of a BTC wallet m/0'/0'/0 and it will generate the necessary private keys.